# How to redirect after some time in Play Framework? - SCALA

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a following problem. When someone enters my index page, I would like them to see it for a while (let's say 2 seconds) and then be redirected to another page. What is the best way to do it in Play Framework? (I tried using WS.url().get as well as calling a method which return Ok - both without any result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use JavaScript/HTML for that. Play will allow you to do server side redirects, which will be instantaneous, for a delay it has to be done client side.